# change an image in pygame after a length of time

Tags: python, image, background, pygame

Hi I am new to this site.
Here is the question.

Currently the program displays an image which is supposed to be the start up screen for three seconds.
I then want it to stop displaying the first image and display another one instead continuously.
I am using pygame version 1.9.1 and python version 2.7.9.
The code is below.
Thanks in advance too.

```
 import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Platypus")

white=255,255,255
black=0,0,0
red=255,0,0

important_platypus=pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Sarah_2/Pictures/no_one_knows_why_Duck_Billed_Platypi_are_important.jpg")
important_platypus=pygame.transform.scale(important_platypus,(600,600))

gameExit=False
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    gameDisplay.blit(important_platypus, (0, 0) )

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.sleep` is the function you want. Below is a full example:

```
 import pygame, sys 
 from pygame.locals import * 
 pygame.init() 
 gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mo de((600,600))
 pygame.display.set_caption ("Platypus")
 time.sleep(3)
 gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mo de((600,600)) 
 pygame.display.set_caption ("second image")
```